# Flutter Firebase push notification - no notification

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a beginner in Flutter. When I tried to make push-notification in my app using cloud functions. I don't why I don't get any push-notifications. It's fine When I use the Firebase tool. But not with Cloud functions.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore.document('shop/{doc}/slides/{docs}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic('shop', {
    notification: {
        title: snapshot.data().username,
        body: snapshot.data().text,
        clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
    },
});
});
```

main.dart

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final fbm = FirebaseMessaging();
    //app in foreground
    fbm.configure(onMessage: (msg) {
      print(msg);
      return;
    },
        //app is terminated.
        onLaunch: (msg) {
      print(msg);
      return;
    },
        //app  in background.
        onResume: (msg) {
      print(msg);
      return;
    });
    fbm.subscribeToTopic('shop');
  }
```

How to send notifications to all without using token or subscribeTopic()?

Comment: is the function is being fired

Comment: Yes. But didn't get any notification

Comment: I am a bit confused by your question, you asked `How to send notifications to all without using token or subscribeTopic()?` to which the answer is: you can't, you have to either use token or subscribe to a topic. However, your code is subscribing to a topic, so is the issue only that the notification is not arriving? If so, have you checked for any error logs in the cloud functions?

Comment: Yesterday, I just assumed either I need to use token or subscribeTopic(). Thank you for your comment. No I haven't checked error log. I will come back after that